# C++ debugger for Notepad++

Tags: c++, debugging, notepad++

I'm using borland c++ 5.5 with notepad++ to compile my C/C++ codes , I need a debugger to debug and watch my code and variables and to use it with notepad++ also . any recommendations ?

Comment: Any reason you are not using a more recent compiler?  Or that you want to debug in Notepad++?  Code::Blocks is a free C++ IDE with a modern compiler.  It supports interactive debugging.

Comment: My recommendation is that you chuck Borland C++ 5.5, and get VisualStudio Express 2010 -- and use it's debugger.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a reason for you not to use a free IDE. I would recommend VC++ express 2010.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Comment: perhaps his code makes use of the features of Borland? For example VCL. This is not portable and can not be compiled on a different compiler. We call this legacy code.